# An issue with fmt tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am currently working on a spring project, and I had to use fmt tags inside my JSPs. In fact fmt tags are working fine for me, and its reading the right value from `messages.properties` file.

for example:

```
<fmt:message key="General.Settings"/>
```

in the `.properties` file:

```
General.Settings=Settings
```

it reads it just perfect.

Now, the issue exists when puting the fmt tag inside another JSTL tags.

For example:

```
<input name="commit" value= <fmt:message key="AllMessages.PostThisMessage"/>
                    type="submit" onclick="return isEmpty();" />
```

Inside `.properties` file:

```
AllMessages.PostThisMessage=Post this message
```

but it displays only the word "Post" instead of "Post this message"

and same with all other fmt tags inside other JSTL tags.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't nest your tags like that, it's confusing and error-prone. Better to do this sort of thing:

```
<fmt:message key="AllMessages.PostThisMessage" var="myMessage"/>
<input name="commit" value="${myMessage}" type="submit" onclick="return isEmpty();" />
```

If you really were using this syntax:

```
value= <fmt:message key="AllMessages.PostThisMessage"/>
```

Then it's a marvel it worked at all, since that would generate invalid HTML.

Comment: +1 For no-nesting in JSP.  I hate when I see code that has tags inside of other opening tags/invalid XML.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes for the value parameter:

`<input name="commit" value="<fmt:message key="AllMessages.PostThisMessage"/>" type="submit" onclick="return isEmpty();" />`

But as already mentioned, nested tags are harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's because of my version of the JST Library, but I couldn't set the `var` directly on the `<fmt:message />`. I had to create a c:set for it to work:

```
<c:set var="buttonEdit">
    <fmt:message key="EDIT" bundle="${yourBundle}"/>
</c:set>
<input class="button edit" type="submit" title="your Title" value="${buttonEdit}"  />
```

I'm new to JSP so I hope that's good. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding single quotes around the value attribute will do the trick.

`<input name="commit" value='<fmt:message key="AllMessages.PostThisMessage"/>'
                    type="submit" onclick="return isEmpty();" />`